# Creating point at specific distance along line in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, performance

I have a road (line) system and would like to place culverts (point) at specific distance along the road. The Construct Points tool creates multiple points spaced out at the users specified interval, but I would like to create a single point at a specified distance. What's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: this is good....but i want to generate points as well as i want to fill the attribute with distance like 10 20 30 40 50.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that this will end up being "the easiest" way to do it, but you can certainly achieve this using Python:

```
points = []
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("line_file", "selected_lines")       # change "line_file"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("selected_lines", ("SHAPE@")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        points.append(row[0].positionAlongLine(10))                    # 10 is the number of units
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(points, 'in_memory\points')              # output layer
```

1. Select your line, or lines.
2. Copy and paste the above script into the ArcMap Python window. Change the input layer, number of units, and output layer.